# Angular 4 http service call fails to call the spring rest service method

Tags: angular, hibernate, spring-boot, angular-http, spring-rest

I am beginner to Angular 4 as well as spring boot rest.

I made a simple app which has Angular 4 as front end and Spring Rest as API. 
I am trying to call Spring Rest controller method (Post) from Angular http request.

Following is the Angular 4 code.

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';


@Injectable()
export class ServerService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

    headers = new Headers({"Content-Type": "application/json"});    

  storeServers(students: any[]) {


    const WEBSERVICE_ADDRESS_STUDENT: string = "http://localhost:8080/api/saveStudent"; 



    return this.http.post(WEBSERVICE_ADDRESS_STUDENT,JSON.stringify(students),{ headers: this.headers })
    .subscribe(
          (response) => console.log(response),
          (error) => console.log("error: ", + error)
        );

  }

}

/************* Following is the student Array *******************/

  student =  [
    {
      StudentID: 102,
      Name: 'abc',
      Surname: 'xyz',
      City: 'Space'
    },
    {
      StudentID: 103,
      Name: 'jack',
      Surname: 'th',
      City: 'Ocean'
    }
  ];
```

Following is my Spring Rest API:

```js
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api")
public class StudentDetailsController {

 private StudentRepository studentRepositor;
 
 @Autowired
 public StudentDetailsController(StudentRepository theStudentDetailDAO)
 {
  this.studentRepositor = theStudentDetailDAO;
 }
 
   
   @RequestMapping(value="/saveStudent", method = RequestMethod.POST,produces = "application/json")
   public void saveStudent(StudentDetails[] objStudentDetails)
   { 
    List<StudentDetails> lstStudentDetais = null; 
    lstStudentDetais = studentRepositor.findAll();    
    
    studentRepositor.save(objStudentDetails[0]);
    
   }

 
}
```

When I hit service from my Angular App it throws following error in my Java application:

```js
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: [Lcom.springboot.cruddemo.entity.StudentDetails;.<init>()
 at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
 at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttribute(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:216) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttribute(ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:84) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:139) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:126) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:166) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
 at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
 at com.luv2code.springboot.cruddemo.rest.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:31) ~[classes/:na]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
 at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
 at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
 at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
 at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
 at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
 at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
 at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_202]
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_202]
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_202]
```

Following is my StudentDetails class and I have defined all the required constructors in there:

```js
package com.luv2code.springboot.cruddemo.entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "StudentDetails")
public class StudentDetails {
 
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
 @Column(name="StudentID")
 private Integer StudentID;
 
 @Column(name="Name")
 private String Name;
 
 @Column(name="Surname")
 private String Surname;
 
 @Column(name="City")
 private String City;
 
 public StudentDetails() {}

 public String getName() {
  return Name;
 }

 public void setName(String name) {
  Name = name;
 }

 public String getSurname() {
  return Surname;
 }

 public void setSurname(String surname) {
  Surname = surname;
 }

 public String getCity() {
  return City;
 }

 public void setCity(String city) {
  City = city;
 }

 public StudentDetails(String name, String surname, String city) {
  Name = name;
  Surname = surname;
  City = city;
 }
 
 

 @Override
 public String toString() {
  return "StudentDetails [Name=" + Name + ", Surname=" + Surname + ", City=" + City + "]";
 }
 
 

}
```

I do not understand which constructor error is referring to :(

following is what chrome developer toolbar says:

```js
error: "Internal Server Error"
message: "No primary or default constructor found for class [Lcom.luv2code.springboot.cruddemo.entity.StudentDetails;"
path: "/api/saveStudent"
status: 500
timestamp: "2019-03-30T06:38:17.757+0000"
trace: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: No primary or default constructor found for class [Lcom.luv2code.springboot.cruddemo.entity.StudentDetails;
↵ at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttribute(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:219)
↵ at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttribute(ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:84)
↵ at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:139)
↵ at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:126)
↵ at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:166)
↵ at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134)
↵ at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
↵ at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
↵ at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800)
↵ at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
↵ at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
↵ at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
↵ at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
↵ at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908)
↵ at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
↵ at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
↵ at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
↵ at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
↵ at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
↵ at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
↵ at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
↵ at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
↵ at com.luv2code.springboot.cruddemo.rest.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:31)
↵ at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
↵ at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
↵ at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
↵ at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
↵ at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
↵ at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
↵ at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)
↵ at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
↵ at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
↵ at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
↵ at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
↵ at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
↵ at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
↵ at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
↵ at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
↵ at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
↵ at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
↵ at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
↵ at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200)
↵ at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
↵ at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
↵ at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
↵ at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
↵ at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
↵ at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
↵ at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
↵ at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
↵ at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834)
↵ at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
↵ at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
↵ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
↵ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
↵ at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
↵ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
↵Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: [Lcom.luv2code.springboot.cruddemo.entity.StudentDetails;.<init>()
↵ at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
↵ at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178)
↵ at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttribute(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:216)
↵ ... 56 more
↵"
```

Following what chrome developer toolbar says about the entire thing:

```js
error: "Internal Server Error"
message: "No primary or default constructor found for class [Lcom.luv2code.springboot.cruddemo.entity.StudentDetails;"
path: "/api/saveStudent"
status: 500
timestamp: "2019-03-30T06:38:17.757+0000"
trace: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: No primary or default constructor found for class [Lcom.luv2code.springboot.cruddemo.entity.StudentDetails;
↵ at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttribute(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:219)
↵ at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttribute(ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:84)
↵ at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:139)
↵ at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:126)
↵ at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:166)
↵ at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134)
↵ at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
↵ at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
↵ at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800)
↵ at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
↵ at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
↵ at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
↵ at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
↵ at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908)
↵ at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
↵ at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
↵ at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
↵ at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
↵ at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
↵ at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
↵ at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
↵ at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
↵ at com.luv2code.springboot.cruddemo.rest.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:31)
↵ at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
↵ at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
↵ at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
↵ at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
↵ at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
↵ at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
↵ at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)
↵ at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
↵ at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
↵ at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
↵ at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
↵ at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
↵ at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
↵ at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
↵ at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
↵ at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
↵ at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
↵ at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
↵ at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200)
↵ at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
↵ at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
↵ at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
↵ at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
↵ at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
↵ at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
↵ at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
↵ at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
↵ at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834)
↵ at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
↵ at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
↵ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
↵ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
↵ at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
↵ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
↵Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: [Lcom.luv2code.springboot.cruddemo.entity.StudentDetails;.<init>()
↵ at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
↵ at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178)
↵ at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttribute(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:216)
↵ ... 56 more
↵"
```

Following is the null element in the array:

[image]

Comment: Plenty of issues here. 1. Using Angular 4, with the deprecated Http service, instead of the latest stable version, with the non-deprecated HttpCLient service. 2. Using `any`. 3. Forgetting to annotated the objStudentDetails argument with `@RequestBody`. 4. using arrays instead of lists. 5. randomly indenting every line of code. 6. subscribing in the service instead of returning an observable and subscribing in the component.

Comment: Is the error because of above 6 points ? I do not think there is issue with Angular code as I used same code with my WCF Rest service of DotNet and it worked.
Something is wrong at Java side.

Comment: No, 3 and 4 are the ones causing the error. But you should definitely start to work on the other ones, too. Making something "work" is not sufficient. Starting a new project with a 2-year old version of a framework is not a wise decision. Plety of bugs and improvements have been made in these 2 years.

Comment: I am new to these things so I might not have followed the best practices. But i do not understand why error is pointing to the constructor of StudentDetails class. As I have already defined the constructors there.

Comment: No, it's pointing at the constructor of the class `[Lcom.luv2code.springboot.cruddemo.entity.StudentDetails;`. That's the class `StudentDetails[]`, i.e. array of StudentDetails.

Comment: Hi JB, Your improvements worked. Now, I can hit my Spring rest method but I am not getting data. List has 2 elements but all those are null at Java side :(
I have added the image in question.

Comment: They are not null. The list has (at least) 3 non null elements. Theire fields are null though. And they are null because, 7. you're not respecting the standard Java and JavaScript naming conventions. Fields start with a lower-case letter, in both languages.

Comment: Sorry, you mean values are null because first letter of variables is capital ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: Hello JB, I made all letters of variable names small in both Angular and Java. Still the values are null :(

Comment: I tried adding 'consumes ="application/json" ' attribute in the java function still values are null   :(

Answer (score 0):

I have executed successfully above code by making small changes.

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveStudent", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
    public void saveStudent(@RequestBody StudentDetails[] objStudentDetailsList) {
        System.out.println(objStudentDetailsList[0].getName());
    }
```

Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "StudentDetails")
public class StudentDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long studentId;
    private String name;
    private String surName;
    private String city;
    public Long getStudentId() {
        return studentId;
    }
    public void setStudentId(Long studentId) {
        this.studentId = studentId;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getSurName() {
        return surName;
    }
    public void setSurName(String surName) {
        this.surName = surName;
    }
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }
    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
```